# Phonetic last and first

Tags: vocabulary

What is the difference between these? Could you give me an example?
Please see the attachment. 
[image]

Comment: Where does this form come from? I've never seen an empty field with this name before. You ask about the difference... so do you know what they mean?

Comment: Perhaps it's asking for a pronunciation guide. 'Swindells'  doesn't tell people how it's pronounced in a given instance. Neither, famously, do 'Bowie' or 'Bernstein'.

Comment: @KannE I think it's so the device (a phone or tablet) knows how to pronounce it (or how you pronounce it). That way, if you say to your voice assistant _Call Jim_, it understands. Or vice versa, if you have a missed call and ask _Who just called me?_ it might reply: _Jim called you 3 minutes ago, would you like to call him back?_ (the voice assistants are very well-mannered). Obviously the voice assistant would know how to say Jim, but it might have more difficulty with JJJ, should it pronounce the letters separately (like F-B-I) or as one big stream of sound (NASA)?

Comment: I  think this is a recondite editing question.

Answer (score 0):

Electronic devices such as Siri are not always able to ‘read’ names correctly, as some commenters have stated, and so the names need to be ‘spelled out’ phonetically so the machine can get what they are.

I think the fields are as follows:

Name: the full name eg:  John Doe

Phonetic Last: Last name, eg Doe, spelled phonetically - such as ‘Doh’ (how Doe sounds)

Phonetic First: First name, eg John, spelled phonetically - such as ‘Jon’ (how John sounds)

Nickname: a short or informal name that John also is known by - such as Jonny.

Comment: I basically agree but phonetic is probably the wrong word. What can one expect from these companies, though?

Comment: Phonetic is the word that describes ‘how something sounds’.

Comment: Yes, and therefore unless you use some phonetic alphabet like the IPA, the letters alone will  not really tell you how something really sounds.

Comment: That’s not the case. Siri is actually able to interpret approximations of phonetic speech, written in English. It’s phenomenally clever. https://www.macworld.com/article/2602878/how-to-correct-siris-pronunciation.html

Comment: Why are you arguing with me? If you write phonetic, it means sound and the sounds of English are not properly rendered with letters. And I am saying these companies do not really give a shit about us or how to explain things. I know what they "mean".